# Color differently the text (options) of a select field in HTML: Mozila firefox issue

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, browser

I want to colour some options in select field (HTML) using JS/Jquery based on the values of the select options assigned. Here is my code:

```
    $('#selectField option[value="val1"]').css({ 'color': 'green' });
```

The code does its job perfectly in the Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, but in Mozilla Firefox nothing happens. Has anybody an alternative for this browser to suggest? The solution must be in JS not in CSS. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="selectField">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>   

$('#selectField option').each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.css({color: $this.val()});
});
```

Comment: Did you try your code? It does not work in Chrome or Firefox. https://jsfiddle.net/fg7wgzpL/

Comment: @MikeChamberlain The option text color appears to work for me when the select dropdown is open in Firefox 47 and Chromium 51.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using a Mac, maybe that is why.

Comment: Yes, most of all it is connected from Safari if does not work, then as option to use library for customization of elements of a form. [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)